# Invalid input 'r': expected 't/T'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Getting the folllowing error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'r': expected
>   't/T' (line 4, column 9 (offset: 116))  "sum(if sr.WScore > sr.LScore
>   then 1 else 0 ) as wins"

Is my logic right????

```
MATCH (t:Teams),(sr:SeasonResults)
WHERE sr.WTeamID=t.TeamID and t.TeamName="x"  
RETURN count(wins),
sum(if sr.WScore > sr.LScore then 1 else 0 ) as wins
```

Comment: Do you have any relationships or just nodes?

Comment: Its nodes MATCH (t:Teams),(sr:SeasonResults)
WHERE sr.WTeamID=t.TeamID and t.TeamName="Alabama"  
RETURN count(wins),
sum (CASE WHEN sr.WScore > sr.LScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wins       I got an error saying that variable wins is undefined

Comment: Looks like `WScore` in `SeasonResults` is a score for the winner team. If that's correct then it will be always greater than `LScore`, and we don't need to compare `WScore > LScore`. Same for `WTeamID`, Is it Winner team ID?

Comment: Yeah basically WScore is score of the winning team, my idea was to compare WScore with LScore if its greater then a value 1 will be assigned to a new variable "wins" and then count the number of wins.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE not IF

```
sum(CASE WHEN sr.WScore > sr.LScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 )
```

Comment: Ok yeah i got to kow about the case statement now, thank you,

MATCH (t:Teams),(sr:SeasonResults)
WHERE sr.WTeamID=t.TeamID and t.TeamName="Alabama"  
RETURN count(wins),
sum (CASE WHEN sr.WScore > sr.LScore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wins

when i tried to run the above piece of code , i got an error "Variable  not defined".
Can't i store the results of the sum in variable wins and display the result. I am able to do it in SQL, but in CQL i am not sure, i am new to Neo4j. Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A `WITH` or `RETURN` clause cannot both *assign* to a variable (like `wins`) AND *use* the same variable. So, a clause like `RETURN COUNT(wins), SUM(...) AS wins` is not supported.

However, if your use case is just to count the number of times in which a related `SeasonResults` node had `WScore > LScore`, you don't need to use `COUNT()`, and this should be sufficient:

```
MATCH (t:Teams), (sr:SeasonResults)
WHERE sr.WTeamID=t.TeamID and t.TeamName="x"
RETURN SUM(CASE WHEN sr.WScore > sr.LScore THEN 1 END) AS wins
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you take the count of `SeasonResults` where  `sr.WTeamID=t.TeamID` will give you the required wins count.

I am assuming `WTeamID` is the ID of the winning team, so when this team's ID is equal to `WTeamID` of `SeasonResults` implies win for this team. And the count of all such a  `SeasonResults` will be total wins for this team.

**You can structure the query for the same as:**

```
MATCH (t:Teams)
WHERE t.TeamName="x"
WITH t
MATCH (sr:SeasonResults)
WHERE sr.WTeamID=t.TeamID
RETURN count(sr) AS wins
```